# how to register jquery events to dynamically added elements which are not child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

With the following piece of code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$j = JQuery.noConflict();
function test() {

  $j("#li1").on(
        "click",
        function() {$j.ajax({
            url : "user/create_user_view",
            success : function(result) {
                $j("#div1").html(result);
            }
          });
        });

}//test()
$j(function(){
test();
});

</script>
</head>
 <body>
  <ul>
    <li id="li1">li1</li>
    <li id="li2">li2</li>
 </ul>
 <div id="div1">div1</div>
 <div id="div2">div2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually the result of ajax call is a html file which is indeed a form,
I want to register events to the added elements of .html file,
I know about `$("parent-selector").on("event","child-selector",callback(){
// code here
});`

How to register js events to elements added dynamically through ajax in div1?

Update: 
 My question is using     `$("parent-selector").on("event","child-selector",callback(){
// code here
});`

will register events only to direct children of #div1 or its descendents too?

Comment: How are they *not* children if you put them inside `#div1`, and that element exists in your HTML when the page loads. Just use `"#div1"` as your parent selector...

Comment: @ http://stackoverflow.com/users/2281280/anoop-joshi : why this question is marked as duplicate,

Comment: @hussainfrotan why isn't this a duplicate..? why is this a special case..? what do you mean content is an `html` file? are you adding another document in a `<div>`.. ?!

Comment: @ Tilwin Joy i have updated my question, i meant all html elements added to #div1 not only direct elements.
because in my case events are not registered to the indirect children of #div1.
for instance #div1>div>form>button, event is not registered to the button even if i use #div1 as parent-selector

Answer (score 1):

You can easyli attach eventhandlers to dynamic elements, you have to write it a little bit diffrent:

```
$('body').on('click', '.myDynamicElement', function(ev) {
    // Do your stuff in here...
});
```

Take a look into this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bMyGY/1/), Cheers Jan